# Components to avoid in Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi, components, delphi-xe2, deprecated

There are a huge number of components that come with Delphi (XE2), many have been around for along time.  Which components should be avoided (the BDE Components for instance), which are out of date (TXPManifest?), and which should be avoided because they are unusable or will just cause grief?

Comment: The `Win 3.1` controls, perhaps? (Unless they are removed from XE2 already...)

Comment: I, for one, am avoiding anything that can be avoided, the less you tie your application logic to the UI the more portable it becomes, say you want to port code to Free Pascal/C++/etc. but that's just my two cents.

Comment: @Andreas The Win3.1 controls are still present in XE2

Comment: I don't think all had understood your question... Also I can't remember nothing that is not deprecated or with bugs that should be avoided. But I think still a good question.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen. Although this is a "List of X" question, it's well-0defined. It's "List of X, where X meets objective criteria".

Comment: I think we must not use any native VCL controls in our NEW projects , Embarcadero has introduced a new framework recently , and Windows is going to introduce a new UI framework called windows Metro

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand - I still (have to) use the TFileList :(

Answer (score 7):

Anything for which you don't have the source. Nothing says "frustrate me" more than not being able to figure out why a component is behaving the way it is because it's poorly documented and being stuck on an old Delphi version because I can't recompile it.

Answer (score 4):

Anything you don't absolutely need.

I am currently maintaining a large application that is dependent on a variety of 3rd party components.  In order to upgrade the application, you need to upgrade the components.  In the case of vendors that are no longer in business, that's a problem.  As a result the entire application is stuck in limbo.